# Crontab permission problem

Tags: permissions, cron, root

I have a fc19 host at work.
This morning `crontab` did not work.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
----------. 1 root root 53472 Jun 11  2013 /usr/bin/crontab
```

The permissions `--------`  means no one has access and can't change rights or rename etc.

To have access to this should the permission be changed to `rwxr-xr-x`?
What can do ?

Comment: As the `root` user you will need to use the `chmod` command to change it to `-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 53472 Jun 11  2013 /usr/bin/crontab` Notice the rw**s** This is the `setuid (set user id)` bit.

Comment: Beyond fixing the symptom, you should investigate why the permissions were changed. Also, note that the file has an SELinux context, which may or may not be correct.

Comment: i dont have any idea what is reason to change the file but now i can't edit, remove, delete, rename, or do anything as root

Answer (score 2):

Correct right to `/usr/bin/crontab` are `-rwsr-xr-x`. So use `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/crontab` to set them.

Comment: chmod 4755 /usr/bin/crontab after that                           chmod: changing permissions of â/usr/bin/crontabâ: Operation not permitted

Comment: You need to run that command as `root` user.

Comment: What about the SELinux context?